# Flink Kuberentes operator not updating job

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've flink cluster deployed to Kubernetes using flink kubernetes operator, I'm copying job to fink docker image which gets deployed successfully (via helm) to job cluster, also my Job uses S3 to save last state, however when I try to update the job i.e deploy the updated version of job (i.e. new docker image with updated jar via helm) then the Job deployment fails with below message

From flink operator

```
Job is not running and HA metadata is not available or usable for executing the upgrade, waiting for upgradeable state
```

From job

```
because the job already reached a globally-terminal state (i.e. FAILED, CANCELED, FINISHED) in a previous execution.
```

My FlinkDeployment yaml file looks like below

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
spec:
  image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}/{{ .Values.image.name }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
  flinkVersion: v1_17
  restartNonce: 1
  ingress:
    template: "api-internal.{{ .Values.env }}.{{ .Values.base_domain }}/{{ .Chart.Name }}(/|$)(.*)"
    className: "nginx"
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "1"
    high-availability.type: kubernetes
    high-availability.storageDir: s3://{{ .Values.ha.bucketName }}/recovery
    state.savepoints.dir: s3://{{ .Values.ha.bucketName }}/savepoints
    state.checkpoints.dir: s3://{{ .Values.ha.bucketName }}/checkpoints
  serviceAccount: sa-{{ .Chart.Name }}
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1048m"
      cpu: 1
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1048m"
      cpu: 1
  job:
    entryClass: com.abc.JobClass
    jarURI: local:///opt/flink/usrlib/job.jar
    args: [ "--runner=FlinkRunner", "--output=file://opt/output.txt" ]
    parallelism: 1
    upgradeMode: last-state
    state: running
    savepointTriggerNonce: 0
```

Appreciate any help on this